# how to add comment in xml subelement at element start

Tags: python, lxml, xml-comments

I am using lxml in an attempt to to output the following xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <students>
        <!-- 
            学生信息表
            "id" : [名字, 数学, 语文, 英文]
        -->
        {
        "1" : ["张三", 150, 120, 100],
        "2" : ["李四", 90, 99, 95],
        "3" : ["王五", 60, 66, 68]
        }
    </students>
</root>
```

This is my code, but the output is not correct:

```
from lxml import etree
with open('student.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
root = etree.Element("root")
child1 = etree.SubElement(root, "students" )
child1.addprevious(etree.Comment('学生信息表 \n "id" : [名字, 数学, 语文, 英文]'))
child1.text = str(data)

# write to file:
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('student.xml', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

The output xml is like this; comment is not in element `<students>`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
    <!--学生信息表 
   "id" : [名字, 数学, 语文, 英文]-->
    <students>{
        "1":["张三",150,120,100],
        "2":["李四",90,99,95],
        "3":["王五",60,66,68]
        }
    </students>
</root>
```

Please help me out on what I am doing wrong and how to proceed.

Comment: Maybe you would like to share with us what should be the correct output? If the correct output is trivial then would you like to share with us debugging details?

Comment: To make the code a proper [mcve], you need to show us the content of student.txt.

Comment: the content of student.txt :        {
        "1" : ["张三", 150, 120, 100],
        "2" : ["李四", 90, 99, 95],
        "3" : ["王五", 60, 66, 68]
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
students = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <students>        
        </students>
    </root> """

student_txt = """{ "1" : ["张三", 150, 120, 100], "2" : ["李四", 90, 99, 95], "3" : ["王五", 60, 66, 68]} """
    
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML(students.encode())

destination = doc.xpath('//students')[0]
destination.text=''    
new_comment = etree.Comment(student_txt)    
new_comment.tail = "\n"+student_txt

destination.insert(0, new_comment)
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <students><!--{ "1" : ["张三", 150, 120, 100], "2" : ["李四", 90, 99, 95], "3" : ["王五", 60, 66, 68]} -->
{ "1" : ["张三", 150, 120, 100], "2" : ["李四", 90, 99, 95], "3" : ["王五", 60, 66, 68]} </students>
</root>
```

Comment: new_comment = etree.Comment('学生信息表 \n "id" : [名字, 数学, 语文, 英文]')

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `addprevious()`, you should use insert as follows:

```
child1.insert(0, etree.Comment('学生信息表 \n "id" : [名字, 数学, 语文, 英文]'))
```

Comment: thks,I use this way,but the comment  at the end of the element.I want before the element.How to?